# Lost Password for Central Administration

Tags: central-administration

I have installed SharePoint 2010 Enterprize and I have a account named administration. Unfortunately I cannot access to SharePoint central administration due to lost password.

Is there any way to enter the SP central administration after I have lost the password?

The goal is to get full access to central administration as administrator role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is THE farm administrator account that was identified during the install, then that account cannot be changed via the interface since that is the account that SharePoint uses to interact with the config database.  I don't believe there is a powershell command for that yet, you will still need to use the stsadm command as follows:

```
stsadm –o updatefarmcredentials –userlogin DOMAIN\username –password password
```

This will update the credentials in the config database and then you can use it to log back into the farm.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the password for the account?  If you've lost it and it's not being used anywhere else, there shouldn't be any reason not to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an admin account with a no expire password (The superuser account).
Create an user with administrator privileges and give permissions in Central Administration